# An interesting pattern in the differences between prime numbers.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Once upon a time, I was looking at interesting properties of prime numbers. One thing I noticed was that if we take the **absolute values of the differences** between each prime, and repeat this process on the differences recursively, the first column turns out to always be $1$ (With the exception of the first row) as demonstrated below for the first $10$ primes:

$$\begin{matrix} p_n & 2 & & 3 & & 5 & & 7 & & 11 & & 13 & & 17 & & 19 & & 23 & & 29 & \cdots \\ 1^{\text{st}}\text{ difference}&& \color{#007777}1 && 2 && 2 && 4 && 2 && 4 && 2 && 4 && 6 \\2^{\text{nd}}\text{ difference}& && \color{#007777}1 && 0 && 2 && 2 && 2 && 2 && 2 && 2 && \\3^{\text{rd}}\text{ difference} &&&&\color{#007777}1 && 2 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 4^{\text{th}}\text{ difference}&&&&&\color{#007777}1 && 2 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ \vdots &&&&&& \color{#007777}1 && 2 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ \vdots&&&&&&&\color{#007777}1 && 2 && 0 && 0 \\ \vdots &&&&&&&&\color{#007777}1 && 2 && 0 \\ \vdots &&&&&&&&&\color{#007777}1 && 2 \\ \vdots &&&&&&&&&&\color{#007777}1\end{matrix}$$

For simplicity, we denote the terms in the form $a_{m,n}$ where $m$ is the row number and $n$ is the column number, like this:
$$\begin{matrix} a_{1,1} & & a_{1,2} & & a_{1,3} & & a_{1,4} && a_{1,5} & \cdots \\ & a_{2,1} &&a_{2,2} && a_{2,3} && a_{2,4} \\ && a_{3,1} && a_{3,2} && a_{3,3} \\ &&& a_{4,1} && a_{4,2} \\ &&&&a_{5,1} \end{matrix}$$

The general form for the differences is given by:
$$a_{m+1,n}=|a_{m,n+1}-a_{m,n}| \tag{1}$$

Therefore, I conjectured the following:

> Let $m$ and $n$ denote the row and column number respectively. Therefore, $a_{m,1}=1$ is true $\forall m\geq 2$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$,

I'd like to know whether this conjecture is true. If so, it would be nice if a proof was provided. Therefore, here I show my thoughts on the problem:

---

The process on $(1)$ of course should be applied recursively to obtain an expression for the elements on the first row. For example, if i put $a_{4,1}$ in terms of the elements of the first row, we obtain:
$$\begin{align} a_{4,1} & =|a_{3,2}-a_{3,1}| \\ &=||a_{2,3}-a_{2,2}|-|a_{2,2}-a_{2,1}|| \\ &=|||a_{1,4}-a_{1,3}|-|a_{1,3}-a_{1,2}||-||a_{1,3}-a_{1,2}|-|a_{1,2}-a_{1,1}||| \end{align}\tag{2}$$
This does not appear obvious as to why the the conjecture is true due to the absolute value signs.

---

Therefore, I decided to abandon using this idea. Somebody had suggested that I use [Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate). I will use the weaker form of the theorem, which states that if $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime, for all $n\geq 1$, then:
$$p_{n+1}<2p_n$$
In that case, I figured that if I apply this on the series with increasing powers of $2$, then:
$$\begin{matrix} \color{#007777}{1} & & \color{#777700}2 & & \color{green}{4} & & \color{orange}8 && 16 & \cdots \\ & \color{#007777}1 && \color{#777700}2 && \color{green}4 && \color{orange}8 \\ && \color{#007777}1 && \color{#777700}2 && \color{green}4 \\ &&& \color{#007777}1 && \color{#777700}2 \\ &&&& \color{#007777}1 \end{matrix}$$
Then each of the columns will have identical values as shown by the different colors above. I figured this was quite similar, and since $p_n\leq 2^n$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, thus this would be true for the primes as well. However, it seems doubtful because the differences are not strictly increasing as we can see in the $2^{\text{nd}} \text{ difference}$ in the prime number series and also, we are taking the absolute value of the differences recursively as shown on the example on $(2)$.

Therefore, I do not think Bertrand's Postulate can be applied directly as I have done.

---

In summary, I'd like to know whether the conjecture is true. If so, a proof would be nice. Otherwise, if the conjecture is false a form of disproof such as a counterexample would be nice.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbreath%27s_conjecture

Comment: @BarryCipra: Short as it is, I think your comment should be an answer.

Comment: If someone knows an heuristic why the conjecture should be true (or not) ?

Comment: See there http://www.paris8.free.fr/ODLYZKO-gilbreath_conjecture.pdf it seems there is an heuristic applying to many sequences whose first element is a 1, the others even, and where the gaps between consecutive elements are not too large and are sufficiently random

Comment: what happens if you started at 5 instead of 2? Can you get a simple formula for the sequence when you start at 5?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have re-discovered [Gilbreath's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbreath%27s_conjecture), namely that creating a sequence in which each term $s_n$ is the difference between the consecutive primes $p_{n+1}-p_n$, and then repeating this process for the newly created sequence, and so forth, will always yield sequences that begin with $s^k_0=1$, for the $k^{th}$ sequence.

Andrew Odlyzko verified the conjecture for $k=3.4 \times10^{11}$ iterations, however, there are no proofs of this conjecture as of today.

---

Your calculations regarding the sequence ${2^n}$ have, unfortunately, nothing to do with Gilbreath's conjecture. It is easily shown that the difference between any consecutive terms $s_n$ and $s_{n+1}$ is:

$$
s_{n+1}-s_n=2^{n+1}-2^n=2^n,
$$

yielding the element in the next sequence $q_n=2^n=s_n$.

Answer (score -4):

```
2   3   5   7   11  13  17  19  23  29  31  37  41  43  47  53  59  61  67  71  73  79  83  89  97  101
    1   2   2   4   2   4   2   4   6   2   6   4   2   4   6   6   2   6   4   2   6   4   6   8   4
        1   1   2   2   2   2   2   4   4   4   2   2   2   2   0   4   4   2   2   4   2   2   2   4
            0   1   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   2   0   0   0   2   4   0   2   0   2   2   0   0   2
                1   1   0   0   0   2   0   0   2   2   0   0   2   2   4   2   2   2   0   2   0   2
                    0   1   0   0   2   2   0   2   0   2   0   2   0   2   2   0   0   2   2   2   2
                        1   1   0   2   0   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   0   2   0   2   0   0   0
                            0   1   2   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   2   0   0
                                1   1   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   2   0
                                    0   1   0   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   2   2   0   0   0   2   2
                                        1   1   2   0   2   0   0   0   0   2   0   2   0   0   2   0
                                            0   1   2   2   2   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   0   2   2
                                                1   1   0   0   2   0   0   2   0   0   0   2   2   0
                                                    0   1   0   2   2   0   2   2   0   0   2   0   2
                                                        1   1   2   0   2   2   0   2   0   2   2   2
                                                            0   1   2   2   0   2   2   2   2   0   0
                                                                1   1   0   2   2   0   0   0   2   0
                                                                    0   1   2   0   2   0   0   2   2
                                                                        1   1   2   2   2   0   2   0
                                                                            0   1   0   0   2   2   2
                                                                                1   1   0   2   0   0
                                                                                    0   1   2   2   0
                                                                                        1   1   0   2
                                                                                            0   1   2
                                                                                                1   1
                                                                                                    0

                                                                                                    103
                                                                                                    2
                                                                                                    2
                                                                                                    2
                                                                                                    0
                                                                                                    2
                                                                                                    0
                                                                                                    0
                                                                                                    0
                                                                                                    0
                                                                                                    2
                                                                                                    2
                                                                                                    0
                                                                                                    0
                                                                                                    2
                                                                                                    0
                                                                                                    0
                                                                                                    0
                                                                                                    2
                                                                                                    0
                                                                                                    0
                                                                                                    0
                                                                                                    0
                                                                                                    2
                                                                                                    0
                                                                                                    1
                                                                                                    1
```

Comment: Go figure A-Z +1

Comment: 01010101... Repeated

Comment: ... was not too difficult to format for readability...

Comment: The differences in second row are wrong. You should delete this

Comment: It's the 2 changed values that that make this work. when adding the columns and subtracting them from the corresponding prime  and running the differences again you get 13 prime doing a count down 5,4,3,2,1,0,1,0,1..... Try and find the 2 incorrect values and explain why changing 2 values gives a repeating 1,0,1,0... Pattern.

Comment: 7, row 2 sould be 0 not 1 and 29, row 2 should be 2 not 4. I have yet to find an end to this pattern

Comment: Believe me, it was hard finding those two to make that happen

Comment: A.    B.    C.    D.    E.  ... (b-a) (c-b) (d-c) (e-d)...  (c-b)-(b-a) (d-c)-(c-b) (e-d)-(d-c) ... ((d-c)-(c-b))-((c-b)-(b-a))  ((e-d)-(d-c))-((d-c)-(c-b)) ...

Comment: To track a negative or not. A negative difference makes things interesting.

Comment: By taking these equations in essence you can get column 103 by reverse engineering column 101. The reason for knowing +1 or -1